# JSF 2.0 How to display a different h:panelGroup each time an item is selected from a selectOneMenu

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I have a selectOneMenu that displays some different stuff categories:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{searchController.selectedCategory}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedCategories()}" >               
        </f:selectItems>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to display a different panelGroup depending on the selected category.
Example(This one needs to be displayed, when the first item is selected)

```
<h:panelGroup id="carInfo">
        <h:outputText value="marka" />
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedCarMarks()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="godina" />
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedYearFrom()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedYearTo()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="kms.:" />
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.kmsFrom()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.kmsTo()}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

I dont know how to do this, because i need to do it with out refreshing the page.
Any ideas? Can Ajax help me here? If so could somebody tell me how please? I am not familiar with at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done easily via ajax:

- Put the `<h:panelGroup>` elements inside an outer `<h:panelGroup>`
- Nest an `<f:ajax>` inside the `<h:selectOneMenu>` and put the id of the outer `<h:panelGroup>` in its `render` attribute.
- Give each of the inner `<h:panelGroup>` elements a `rendered` attribute that evaluates to true only if the corresponding category is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You said "Without Page Refresh" in that case there are 2 ways you can achieve this:
**1. AJAX:** You have to attach cartInfo id with onChange event on your selectOneMenu
 which will reRender cartInfo panelGroup
**Example:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{searchController.selectedCategory}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedCategories()}" >               
        </f:selectItems>
      <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="cartInfo"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

*Note: You have to have some attribute in panelGroup to eveluate to true on change event.*

**2. JavaScript:** You can have your Panel inside the div and can show/hide div again on onChange event.
**Example:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{searchController.selectedCategory}" onChnage="javascript: showDivFunction()">
```

...

```
<div id="divCartInfo" style="display:none">
<h:panelGroup id="carInfo">
.....
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using JSF2, you don't necessarily need Ajax4jsf.

Comment: @BC Thx for highlighting that. Updated my answer :-)

Comment: I managed to do it finally :) 
<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="menuType" />

And in the panel:

<h:panelGroup id="menuType">
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchController.selectedCategory == 'automobili'}">
  ...

Thank you very much guys!!

Answer (score 1):

---

I am very near the solution, but something is wrong. Ive done every thing as you said: 1st and 2nd problem are solved. The problem is that the panel carInfo does not get rendered when i pick the category.

Is there something wrong with the method in the managed bean?
For some reason it does not get called.
This is how my code currently looks like
Managed bean

```
 public void carSelectedEvent(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    String tmp = (String) e.getNewValue();
    System.out.println("CALLED!!!!!");
    if (selectedCategory.trim().equals("automobili")) {
        carCategorySelected = true;
    } else if (e.getNewValue().toString().contains("NEKRETNINE")) {

    }
}
```

JSF page Select

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="searchController.selectedCategory">
        <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.formatedCategories()}" ></f:selectItems>
        <f:ajax event="change" action="searchController.carSelectedEvent" render="carInfo"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

JSF panel that needs to be displayed

```
<h:panelGroup id="carInfo" rendered="searchController.carCategorySelected">
...
```

When i navigate to the page everithing seems ok but i notice this message in the console:

> INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have
>   been displayed. sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(One or more
>   resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been
>   defined within the view.), detail=(One or more resources have the
>   target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the
>   view.)]

Comment: Question 1st- I dont really know how to get the String that represents the selected value if the page is not refreshed
Answer - Create a new string variable and use in the selectOneMenu
Quest 2nd- It all the time displays both panels...
Answer - Do not use <c:if> instead put rendered="bean.booleanField" in panelGroup
Quest 3rd- What should i actually do... in the panels?
Answer - Check the value of newly created String variable and take decision accordingly.
Also, you can use <f:ajax> as you are using JSF2.0

Comment: You should not post questions as answers. Either edit your question to update it or post a new question if it concerns a different concrete problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Ok i will keep that on mind i will not post questions as answers. It is my first day on de forum, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.), detail=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.)]

Check your head tag , you may have missed the h prefix , write h:head , I solved the problem by using the prefix h.