# reRender a panelGroup or region depending on what is selected on selectOneRadio

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

It's basically this Question:
[JSF 2.0 How to display a different h:panelGroup each time an item is selected from a selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977651/jsf-2-0-how-to-display-a-diferent-hpanelgroup-each-time-an-item-is-selected-from)

But i'm using selectOneRadio and I don't have the f:ajax that the answers says it fixes.
Any idea of what I could do to reRender my panelGroups?

I've tried with a4j:support but no success. It looks like it's going to reRender but nothing changes. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. So, I've put an onclick="submit()" on the selectOneRadio and it worked but it loads the whole page again.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.selectedItem}" >
 <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="regionSomeItem,regionAnotherItem" />
 <div class="cssClass">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="someItem" itemLabel="Some Item"/>
 </div>
 <div class="cssClass">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="anotherItem" itemLabel="Another Item"/>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

---

```
<a4j:region id="regionSomeItem" rendered="#{condition for some item}"/>

<a4j:region id="regionAnotherItem" rendered="#{condition for another item}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make a group outside the a4j:region with no tag rendered. It seems to conflict with the tag reRender of what is trying to reRender it.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.selectedItem}" >
 <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="allItemsInOneGroup" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGroup id="allItemsInOneGroup">

<a4j:region rendered="#{condition for some item}">
</a4j:region>

<a4j:region rendered="#{condition for another item}">
</a4j:region>

</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: i'm already doing it. it doesn't work, unless i put on reRender a "submit()" that refreshes the whole page :(

Comment: @pringlesinn - can you edit your question and add the regions you are reRendering?

Comment: I edited your answer cause i found the answer and didn't want to answer in another place.