# Disable JSF form field validation when submit

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf

I have a `<h:selectOneMenu>`. Depending on what is selected will be shown one of the many `<div>`s related to the selection and will be hidden the others.
Each `<div>` has some `<h:inputText>` that write to different `@ViewScoped` beans. Some of this `<div>`s even write to the same properties in the beans.

Ex.

```
<div>
    <h:outputLabel for="list" value="Items"/>
    <div>
        <h:message for="list"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{bean.selectedItem}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one"></f:selectItem>
             <f:selectItems value="bean.someItemsList" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="item1">
    <!-- some other input fields -->
    <div>
        <h:message for="item1input1"/>
        <h:inputText id="item3input1" value="bean.thisIsTheSameProperty" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="item2">
    <!-- some other input fields -->
</div>
<div id="item3">
    <!-- some other input fields -->
    <div>
        <h:message for="item3input1"/>
        <h:inputText id="item3input1" value="bean.thisIsTheSameProperty" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem: When I select an item that will display a `<div>` (ex. `<div id="item1">`) and there is also another hidden `<div>` (ex. `<div id="item3">`) that writes to the same bean properties (ex. `value="bean.thisIsTheSameProperty"`) and this properties are annotated with `javax.validation.constraints.@NotNull`, even I give a value to this input fields, when I submit the form, I think JSF runs also the hidden `<div>` (which normally has no input set).

What I see during debugging: When the form will be submited I see the setter of the bean will be called twice. The first time the bean properties will be set with the correct valeus I typed in but the second time the setter will be called with null values. So the validation will fail because of the @NotNull.

My assumption is that JSF tries to set the bean values twice, one for the input fields on the shown `<div>` and the second time for the hidden `<div>` (because they point to the same bean properties), but for the hidden bean there are not input fields set (they are null).

I show/hide the `<div>`s with jQuery depending on the item selected from the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.
Ex.

```
$('#item1').show();
$('#item1').hide();
$('#item2').show();
$('#item2').hide();
$('#item3').show();
$('#item3').hide();
```

Is there a way to say JSF to not consider the hidden `<div>`s at all?

Comment: Your binding 'bean.thisIsTheSameProperty' was transmitted twice, because you have two input fields, that bind this property. You can try to disable the input fields in the hidden <div>. Disabled fields will not transferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that hidden inputs (hidden via CSS) are not submitted to the server. This assumption is wrong and it is a plain html thing btw, not JSF related at all.

See e.g. [Stop an input field in a form from being submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008035/stop-an-input-field-in-a-form-from-being-submitted)

But still, it would allow client-side manipulation via a browser developer tool to 'attack' you application. JSF, contrary to all the hyped javascript UI frameworks is a full grown '[MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-)' that has build in protection against [client-side manipulation/tampering and CSRF, XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf) for which you'd need OWASP related functionality in other framework. (That and other things makes JSF (with PrimeFaces, OmniFaces and DeltaSpike) for me still a great framework to quickly develop business oriented applications.)

You'd better use `ajax` to [conditionally render one div or the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977651/jsf-2-0-how-to-display-a-different-hpanelgroup-each-time-an-item-is-selected-fr) but you cannot ['update' the divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/is-it-possible-to-update-non-jsf-components-plain-html-with-jsf-ajax) when they are defined like you have them.

**See also:**

- [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo/)

Comment: What I actually need is hidden inputs (hidden via CSS or some other way) not to be submited.

Comment: Then use the pure html/javascript 'solution' in the first link in the answer, but as you can see from the upvotes, what I propose is the better solution

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Kukeltje and comment from @drkunibar worked for me.
I modified it a little.

Actual solution:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
            if($('#list').find(':selected').val() === 'itemOption1') {
                $('item3').remove();
            } else if($('#list').find(':selected').val() === 'itemOption3') {
                $('item1').remove();
            }
});
```

I check to see which option is selected. If option1 is selected then I remove the `div` with id`item3` from the DOM, or else if the option3 is selected then I remove the `div` with id`item1` from the DOM.
In this way the binding `bean.thisIsTheSameProperty` is transmitted only one and the values will not be overriden.

Thank you.

Comment: That is what is mentioned in the links in my answer. If this is what you need, it is in **no way** JSF related and effectively a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008035/stop-an-input-field-in-a-form-from-being-submitted. and there is no need to add it as an answer then. But keep in mind, this is an insecure solution.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. Thank you!
But I cannot find out how and why it is an insecure solution. My solution hast nothing to do with CSRF-attacks. Do you see something that I don't? :)

Comment: 'client-side tampering' is also mentioned in the answer. Not just CSRF and XSS

Comment: In my case it is up to user to do what he wants. There is no sensitive data or process that I need to secure. Otherwise I would have developed the logic on the server side. But thank you.